# Since we upgraded to Artifactory 7.24.3 from 7.21. We are unable to browse content in jar file using JAR! in the URL

Tags: jar, self-hosting

We store test report site in Artifactory as a jar file. We use the "Allow Content Browsing" to browse the html format reports. We are unable browse anymore anything within the jar file. We are getting a 404 resource not found error. We have self hosted instance.

http:///artifactory//org//latest-SNAPSHOT/site-jarfile.jar!/allure-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Can you please clarify more? The English is very poor

Comment: Not sure which part is unclear to you. This turned out to be a bug in Artifactory and they have provided us a workaround for it.